# T-SQL Get all years from - to

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to find a lists with the sales of each Shop for each year from a database. But i want to print all years with 0 sales as well (for some years/shops there will be no data in my database)

I have done the following procedure but it only returns Years and shops which have non zero values .

```
SELECT   YEAR(temp.INVOICE_DATE) AS Year, Shop.Name, SUM(temp.QTY * Product.Price) AS Total
FROM    (
            SELECT  pci.INVOICE_ID, ci.STORE_ID, ci.INVOICE_DATE, pci.PRODUCT_ID, pci.QTY 
            FROM    [Product_Customer Invoice] pci, [Customer Invoice] ci
            WHERE   pci.INVOICE_ID = ci.INVOICE_ID
        )AS temp, Product, Shop
WHERE   Product.PRODUCT_ID = temp.PRODUCT_ID AND Shop.STORE_ID = temp.STORE_ID  
GROUP BY YEAR(temp.INVOICE_DATE), Shop.Name
ORDER BY Year ASC
```

I get The following result

[image]

I would like to ask for any ideas how to include 0 for years or shops that not any sales has been done

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY ALL YEAR(temp.INVOICE_DATE), Shop.Name`? (note the "ALL")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the data you want:

```
SELECT y.Year, s.Shop.Name,
       COALESCE(SUM(pci.QTY * p.Price), 0) AS Total
FROM Shop s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT invoice_date as year FROM [Product_Customer Invoice]
     ) y LEFT JOIN
     [Product_Customer Invoice] pci
     ON YEAR(pci.invoice_date) = y.year AND
        pci.store_id = s.store_id LEFT JOIN
     Product p
     ON pci.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY y.year, s.name
ORDER BY y.year, s.name;
```

Notice that this also fixes your `join` syntax and removes the unnecessary subquery.

This assumes that all the years you want are in `[Product_Customer Invoice]`.  If you want a different set of years, either explicitly list them using `VALUES()`, use a recursive CTE to generate them, or use a calendar table.